# Why is the operator precedence not followed here?

Tags: java, operators, operator-precedence

In this code:

```
int y = 10;
int z = (++y * (y++ + 5));
```

**What I expected**

First `y++ + 5` will be executed because of the precedence of the innermost parentheses. So value of `y` will be 11 and the value of this expression will be 15. Then `++y * ()` will be executed. So 12 * 15 = 180. So z=180

**What I got**

z=176

This means that the VM is going from left to right not following operator precedence. So is my understanding of operator precedence wrong?

Comment: Precedence does NOT mean the order things are executed.

Comment: I'm always wondering why people even try to use this construct. If it's hard to figure out what happens (and needs a question on SO), then it's probably not suitable for production. I wouldn't be too happy if people on my team gave me this code at least. Just my two cents, and not an actual answer and/or question.

Comment: @Caramiriel I'm 99% sure this is not production code - this is just prodding and poking at the language & compiler, and the OP feels that they have found something unexpected.

Comment: Euhm I dont program in Java at all and even I knew the result should have been 11*16. Isn't this like basic math or something?

Comment: @Loko Basic math doesn't have constructs like `y++`, since basic math doesn't have mutable variables (as far as I know).

Comment: @Kritzefitz okay a very tiny bit programming knowledge and some math knowledge

Comment: Considering how much creators of Java tried to improve safety from C/C++, it's seems silly they didn't prohibit this. Compiler giving error straight away would have been a lot more productive, than countless people trying to figure out how the expression works.

Comment: Your understanding of operator precedence is wrong; this is a very common misunderstanding and many beginner books explain this completely wrong. These articles are about C# but the principles apply equally well to Java; they might help you. http://ericlippert.com/tag/precedence/

Comment: The key thing to understand is that precedence determines the order in which the *operators* are executed, not the order in which the *operands* are executed. `A() + B() * C()` guarantees that the multiplication operation happens before the addition. **The invocation of `A()` is neither a multiplication nor an addition**, so precedence says *nothing whatsoever* about whether `A()` happens before `B()` and `C()`.

Comment: Moreover: don't forget about *associativity*. In  `A() + B() - C() * D()` is the multiplication done *before* or *after* the addition?  It is done *after*. The multiplication comes before the subtraction because of precedence, the addition comes before the subtraction because of associativity. So we have `(A() + B()) - (C() * D())`. We compute the left side of the subtraction *before* the right side, and therefore the addition must happen *before* the multiplication.

Comment: In-lining a `++` should be a syntax error. Then we wouldn't have all this confusion over it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The expression (++y * (y++ + 5)); will be placed in a stack something like this:

```
1. [++y]
2. [operation: *]
3. [y++ + 5] // grouped because of the parenthesis
```

And it will be executed in that order, as result

```
1. 10+1 = [11] // y incremented 
2. [operation: *]
3. 11+5 = [16] // y will only increment after this operation
```

The the expression is evaluated as

```
11 * 16 = 176
```

Comment: If you are working on a stack, the [operation: \*] should come *after* the two inputs. It doesn't affect the important bits of what you're saying here, so it's just a minor quibble.

Comment: I find this answer quite confusing. If you're considering a stack machine, the operations are: compute the side effect and value of ++y and push the result on the stack, then compute the side effect and value of y++ and put the result on the stack, then push 5 on the stack, then pop two things off the stack, add them, and push the sum on the stack, then pop two things off the stack, multiply them, and put the product on the stack.

Comment: Okay, using post-fix notation it is expressed as `[++y][y++][5]+*` or `11 11 5 +  *`. During he first phase parsing it will push the 3 values into the stack `[5][11][11]` in that order. Next it will find the `+` operator and it will pop 2 values from the stack `11` and `5`, the result of the operation, which is `16`, will be pushed back into the stack, hence the stack state will be `[16][11]`. The next token is another operator `*`, so it will pop 2 values from the stack again and perform the operation: `11 * 16` (note: the 2nd value popped will be the first operand).

Comment: @OwenBringino Realistically a high level programming language will not use a "stack", it will implement the rules of the grammar. So your analogy falls apart easily.

Answer (score 14):

> First y++ + 5 will be executed because of the precedence of the innermost parentheses

Precedence and evaluation order are not the same thing. All binary expressions except the assignment expression are evaluated left-to-right. Therefore `y++` is evaluated before the parenthesized expression on the right.

Comment: But then I don't understand the point of using parentheses in mathematical expressions

Comment: @EdmDroid Without any parenthesis, `++y * y++ + 5`  would be evaluated just as `(++y * y++) + 5` - that's a very different expression.

Comment: I guess the choice of the term "precedence" causes confusion. It's actually *binding priority*, regulating how a chain of binary operations parses syntactically, and not a temporal precedence.

Comment: While OP is confused, so is the answer: "All binary expressions except the assignment expression are evaluated left-to-right" is not correct or at least confusing: the multiplication is performed  _after_ the addition although the latter is to the right of the multiplication. What is true that among pairs of *non-overlapping* formulas, the leftmost one is evaluated before the rightmost one; concretely this applies to `++y` on the left and `y++` or its containing `y++ + 5` on the right. On the other hand the formulas with `*` respectively `+` as operator overlap (latter is operand of former).

Comment: The latter is not to the right of multiplication, it is the right *side* of the binary multiplication expression. The rule is very simple: evaluate the left operand, then evaluate the right operand, then evaluate the binary expression itself. No overlaps need to be considered, the expressions are strictly nested into a tree structure.

Answer (score 12):

The parentheses just describe how the sub-expressions will be grouped together. Parenthesizing doesn't mean it will be evaluated first. Rather, the rule in java is *evaluate each sub-expression strictly from left to right*.

Always remember that **the order of evaluation has absolutely nothing to do with *operator precedence* and *associativity***.

Java Oracle documentation says that:

#### [15.7. Evaluation Order](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.7)

> The Java programming language **guarantees** that the **operands of operators appear to be evaluated** in a specific evaluation order, namely, **from left to right**.

Therefore, the expression `(++y * (y++ + 5))` will be evaluated as

```
temp1 = ++y = 11
temp2 = y++ + 5 = 11 + 5 = 16 
z = temp1*temp2 = 11*16 = 176
```

Further reading: [Eric Lippert's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) blog, [Precedence vs Associativity vs Order](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/23/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order.aspx?Redirected=true), explained in detailed about *precedence*, *associativity* and *order of evaluation*. Though this blog addresses [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) but equally valid for [java](/questions/tagged/java) too.

Answer (score 4):

1. First will be executed `++y`. `y` will be `11`.
2. Then will be executed `y + 5` (actually `y++ + 5` can be written as `5 + y++` which is interpreted as `(5 + y)` and then `y++`). `z` will become `11 * 16 = 176`.
3. `y` will be `12` after the calculation finishes.

Comment: postfix ++ has higer precedence than binary +. It just happens that the value of the expression y++ is the value of y before the increment, but y is incremented as a side effect.

Comment: Why `5 + y++` will be interpreted as `(5 + y)++` ?

Comment: I meant `(5 + y)` and then `y++`

Comment: Still wrong. It is not necessary that side effect to `y`  will take place after `y + 5`.

Comment: Indeed, this answer is misleading. Though in this case you cannot tell whether the increment side effect happens before or after the addition, you can come up with an example where you *can* tell the difference. Java does not allow the side effect of the increment to be delayed until after the addition.  (Imagine a world for instance where addition could throw an exception on overflow; the side effect of the increment must be observed *before* the exception is possibly thrown, because a catch could observe the incremented variable.)

Answer (score 1):

The calculation is going on following order

```
 z= (++10 * (10++ + 5))
 z= (11 * (11 + 5))//++ (prefix or postfix) has higher precedence than + or *
 z= (11 * 16)
 z= 176
```

Comment: Four upvotes to a wrong answer !! o.O

Comment: @haccks well to be fair, you haven't done anything to help people understand _why_ it's wrong...

Comment: @DavidZ; Do you agree with the statement: *Here right part will be evaluated first because of ()*?

Comment: Precedence has nothing to do with order of evaluation.