# Can anyone explain the output process in java

Tags: java, output

```java
int p=15, q=12, s;  
s=p/q*++p%(++p%--q);
System.out.print(s);
```

I am trying it according to the precedence of operators and associativity but I think it should give me the output `2` but it is giving me `4` as output.

Comment: Could you please remove the parts that you understand and only show the operations that you think should be working differently?

Comment: I think it should solve the bracket first

Comment: Inside the bracket it will be16%11=5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are the rules for evaluation order in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800590/what-are-the-rules-for-evaluation-order-in-java)

Comment: It is essential to understand that order of evaluation is distinct from operator precedence. Order of evaluation is left to right.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29162301/why-is-the-operator-precedence-not-followed-here?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Assuming OP knows the effects of `++` and `--`.

Answer (score 2):

### Precedence

```java
p/q*++p%(++p%--q)
```

is computed as

```java
((p / q) * (++p)) % ((++p) % (--q))
```

using the [operator precendece rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html).

Note that `++x`/`--x` increment/decrement the variable by one and then return the result after the operation. Since they change the variable itself, the effect obviously carries over to other usages of the variable.

### Evaluation

It is then evaluated **left to right**, the math is

```java
((15 / 12) * (16)) % ((17) % (11))
```

which results in `4`:

```java
  ((15 / 12) * (16)) % ((17) % (11))
= (1 * 16) % 6
= 16 % 6
= 4
```